# Select last record in group using hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate

I want to get this SQL using criterias

```
select A.evaluated_employee_id, A.created_date, A.total_grade
from employee_performance_assessment A
join
(  select evaluated_employee_id, max(created_date) as maxdate, status, total_grade
    from employee_performance_assessment
    group by evaluated_employee_id
) B on A.evaluated_employee_id = B.evaluated_employee_id and A.created_date = B.maxDate
```

I am doing the following

```
    DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(EmployeePerformanceAssessmentBO.class);
    dc.createAlias("evaluatedEmployee", "e");
    dc.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.max("createdDate"))
.add(Projections.groupProperty("evaluatedEmployee")));
 dc.addOrder(Order.asc("e.lastName")).addOrder(Order.asc("createdDate"));                   
    dc.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    return getDAOHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(dc);
```

But this generates the subquery inside the WHERE clause
Any idea how to join two criterias from the same table (class)?

Comment: Subqueries are not supported in the from clause of HQL queries. And Criteria only supports a subset of HQL.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, so a solution would be to execute native sql?

Comment: Yes. You'll need SQL for such subqueries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get to a solution. Basically changed the original query by:

```
select A.evaluated_employee_id, A.created_date, A.total_grade
from employee_performance_assessment A
where A.created_date = 
(  select max(created_date)
    from employee_performance_assessment
    where A.evaluated_employee_id = evaluated_employee_id 
    group by evaluated_employee_id
)
```

So instead of joining to a subquery I compare created_date in where clause.
And the equivalent in hibernate would be:

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(EmployeePerformanceAssessmentBO.class, "performanceAssessment");
dc.createAlias("evaluatedEmployee", "e");

dc.addOrder(Order.asc("e.lastName")).addOrder(Order.asc("createdDate"));

if (assessmentsSearch.isOnlyLastAssessment()){
   DetachedCriteria dc2 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(EmployeePerformanceAssessmentBO.class, "performanceAssessmentSubQuery");
   dc2.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.max("createdDate")));
   dc2.add(Expression.eqProperty("performanceAssessment.evaluatedEmployee.id", "performanceAssessmentSubQuery.evaluatedEmployee.id"));

   dc.add(Subqueries.propertyEq("createdDate", dc2));
}
```

Hope it helps someone else.